# Bash redirect is being treated as a parameter

Tags: bash

I have a function that takes a command (call to tool plus parameters) that I want to run, and redirect its output.  The redirect (in this case >&2 because I want to send it to stderr) is in the variable redirect, the command is in the variable command. I've tried calling this two separate ways:

```
'$command $redirect'

$command $redirect
```

In both cases, the redirect gets treated as a parameter of the call in command, rather than as a redirect.

Note: if I do this:

```
$command >&2
```

Then it works correctly

---

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get it to redirect to an arbitrary target?

Comment: Redirections are syntax, not values. You can't embed them in parameters without using `eval` (which opens a whole other can of worms best avoided).

Comment: @chepner I need to leave callers of the function the ability to do arbitrary redirects (> >> 1>&2 > foo.txt etc), so I'm probably going to have to go with eval.  Thank you for the explanation of the problem

Comment: Perhaps you should just define a function that encapsulates the *commands*, and let the caller apply whatever redirections they want to the function call? `eval` is almost always the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since redirection is part of the shell syntax for a command, and not an argument passed *to* a command, you can't put the redirection operator in a parameter. (The shell scans the command for redirection operators *before* parameter expansion occurs, and does not look again *after* parameter expansion.)

What you can do is put the *file* to redirect to in a parameter, and hard-code the operator.

```
errorFile=foo

$command 2> "$errorFile"
```

(I will ignore any issues with trying to embed a command and its arguments in a single parameter for this question.)

If you don't want to redirect at all, use `/dev/stderr` as a default value for `errorFile`; whether this is a file system entry or not, `bash` will treat it (in redirection only) as the inherited standard error, whatever its real path might be.

Comment: Perhaps also `if [ "$errorfile" ]; then exec 2>"$errorfile"; fi` or something like that for conditional redirection.

Comment: I'd hesitate to globally redirect standard error like this.